# TYPO3 hook for modifing TCE data from database

Tags: typo3

I'm looking for a hook that let's me modify the database output, when editing my extension in the backend, before it's printed to the TCE fields.

I tried getSingleField_preProcess in class.t3lib_tceforms.php but that did not contain any relevant data to my extension.

Comment: Let me understand, do you want to manipulate the data of the currently saved record of your ext, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSingleField_preProcess` should be the correct hook for what you want. I think the problem is that your function is called for records of **every** table, not just yours. You have to differentiate when to do any processing based on the table that is being rendered. The name of the table is passed to your `getSingleField_preProcess()` method.

Your **ext_localconf.php** should register your hook:

```
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tceforms.php']['getSingleFieldClass'][] = 'tx_yourextension_be';
```

...where **tx_yourextension_be** is the name of your class designated for the backend processing. This class then must contain `getSingleField_preProcess()` method:

```
public function getSingleField_preProcess($table, $field, &$row, $altName, $palette, $extra, $pal, &$pObj) {
  // ...processing...
}
```

As you see, several variables are passed to your method. `$table` contains the name of the table to which the processed record belongs to. `$field` is the name of the field that is being rendered. `$row` contains the whole record that you can manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to use `TCEmain` hook

```
function processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray(array &$incomingFieldArray, $table, $id, t3lib_TCEmain &$reference) {
    if ($table == 'tx_yourext_table') {
        $a = $incomingFieldArray['field_a'];
        $b = $incomingFieldArray['field_b'];            
        $incomingFieldArray['field_c'] = $a . ' ' . $b;
    }
}
```

OR/AND

```
function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations($status, $table, $id, $fieldArray, &$reference) {
    if ($table == 'tx_yourext_table') {
        if ($status == 'update') {
            $this->doSomethingWithRecordAfterUpdate($id);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you need to register the hook in `ext_localconf.php` of your extension, for an example:

```
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass']['yourext']
         = 'EXT:yourext/class.tx_yourext_tcemain.php:tx_yourext_tcemain';
```